# How to write regular expression for this kind of a string?

Tags: php, regex

I will get this kind of string from the `$_POST` array:

```
$string = "\"Search Text\"";
```

OR

```
$string = '\'Search Text\'';
```

How I will check whether the Search Text included in double quotes or single quotes using regular expression.

---

Base on Kolink Answer I did like this

```
echo $subject = "'Search Text'";
$pattern = "/['\"](?=;$)/";
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
```

Its not giving any result. :(

Comment: Something is amiss here: Why not just use `strpos($string, '"');` OR `strpos($string, "'");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to clarify, your user will be sending something like `$string = "Search Text";` in the textbox? Or is that just a part of your server-side code?

If it's the first, you can just search for `/['"](?=;$)/` and that will tell you if single or double quotes were used.

If it's the second, your question makes no sense since the quotes are not a part of the string.

Comment: Hi How I will use this with php preg_match. I tried like this but its giving error
preg_match(your expression, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);

Comment: Hi based on your answer I tried but No result. Please check my question. There I posted my codes

Comment: Well now you've actually specified what your string is, just get the first character (`substr($string,0,1)`)

Comment: Hi kolink I need regular expression. I know how to use substr